# How can I display tags on one line

Tags: 8, theming, taxonomy-terms

How to change the below output of a drupal article Tags display with bootstrap theme

[image]

To something like this which is displayed in stackoverflow below any questions

[image]

Is there a ready made module available, I know this can be achieved using JS tagEditor plugin for jQuery

I tried to use `Expert` Field format mode in `Display Suite` by setting `span` for the item tag, it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using below CSS

```
.field--name-field-tags .field--item {
   display: inline;
}

.field--name-field-tags .field--item a, 
.field--name-field-tags .field--item a:visited,
.field--name-field-tags .field--item a:active,
.field--name-field-tags .field--item a:hover {
   color: #fff;
   background-color: #ff5588;
   padding: 1px 5px 1px 5px;
   border-radius: 3px;
}
```

which gave this output

[image]

I used [Asset Injector](https://www.drupal.org/project/asset_injector) which is easy online edit